# Can't deploy maui app to iOS after updating from .net 7 to .net8. A bundle identifier is required

Tags: maui

My MAUI iOS app works fine on .net 7.

I updated to VS2002 Preview 7.0 today and updated the project to .net 8 following these instructions.
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Upgrading-.NET-MAUI-from-.NET-7-to-.NET-8

Android and Windows apps build and deploy.

iOS will build but not deploy to similar or local device.

2>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.0.8477-net8-rc2.2\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(612,3): error : A bundle identifier is required. Either add an 'ApplicationId' property in the project file, or add a 'CFBundleIdentifier' entry in the project's Info.plist file.

The strange thing is that my project file has an application id in it.  When I look through the build log I even see:
ApplicationId = com.companyname.mobile.maui

I went back to .net 7 to confirm everything works on iOS.

I tried adding the CFBundleIdentifier to the info.plist.

Not sure how to troubleshoot this further.  Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: The problem in this link is similar to yours, you can refer to the solution in the link：[Missing 'ApplicationId' error in MAUI .Net 8](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Missing-ApplicationId-error-in-MAUI-N/10424061?q=Localization&sort=newest)

Answer (score 1):

I had a second MAUI project in my solution that was still using .net 7.0. After I updated it to .net8.0, iOS works as expected.